# How to unit test methods that are using streams?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I'm new to unit tests and I'm looking for a way to test methods with streams but so far I couldn't find an example on the internet.

I have two methods with streams in a service class:

```
public List<Appointment> getAppointmentsForToday() {

    return getAppointmentsForSpecificDoctor().stream()
        .filter(appointment -> appointment.getDate().equals(LocalDate.now()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
  }

  public ObservableList<String> getScheduledTime(User pickedDoctor, LocalDate pickedDate) {
    List<Appointment> appointmentsOfDoctor = getAllAppointments()
        .stream()
        .filter(appointment -> appointment.getDoctor().getFirstName().equals(pickedDoctor.getFirstName()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

    List<Appointment> appointmentsInSpecificDay = appointmentsOfDoctor
        .stream()
        .filter(appointment -> appointment.getDate().equals(pickedDate))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

    Iterator<Appointment> it = appointmentsInSpecificDay.iterator();
    ObservableList<String> scheduledHours = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    while(it.hasNext()) {
      scheduledHours.add(it.next().getTime());
    }

    return scheduledHours;
  }
```

How should I approach to those?

Comment: The fact the method uses streams is irrelevant to the unit test. You test that you get the expected return value (or exception) for a given input.

Comment: Oh okay, thank you.